# Can regex do this?

Tags: regex, pywikibot

Before:

```
=={{int:filedesc}}==
{{Information
|description = wikiwoordenboek audio
|date =
|source =
|author =
|permission =
|other_versions =
}}
[[Category:Dutch pronunciation|Example]]
```

Is it possible to find whatever is between `|` and `]]`, and then use it to replace "wikiwoordenboek audio"

After:

```
=={{int:filedesc}}==
{{Information
|description = Example
|date =
|source =
|author =
|permission =
|other_versions =
}}
[[Category:Dutch pronunciation|Example]]
```

Comment: You should show your desired output.  Should the line containing `wikiwoordenboek audio` become `|description = Example`?  Is the pattern match triggered by `|description =` or `wikiwoordenboek audio` or something else? Is the whole block of text in memory?  Is there anything else in the memory, or just this content?  Should the last line be left unmodified?  Which sub-species of 'regex' are you using?  Is the host language Python or something else?

Comment: Can you please show an example of what you would like your "after" text to look like? Your string `|(.*)]]` would seem to be a syntax error for Wiki markup, so I think it should be `|(.*)}}`.

Comment: Try [`(?s)[\r\n]*\|.*?]]`](https://regex101.com/r/sC9dK6/1)

Comment: `s/\|[^\]]+\]\]/|wikiwoordenboek audio]]/g`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Desired output added. Host language python. Description that needs to be replaced stays consistent, additional text may appear in front of source, date etc.

Comment: @KenY-N (.*) is not part of the wiki mark up, hence not being in the code block. I have added the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
(\|description =\s*)([^\n]+)(.*\[\[)([^\|]+\|)([^]]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zW9kB3/3)

Comment: I apologize for my poor question, what I meant got lost in translation. As shown by the desired output that I have added to the original question, I am looking for it to replace "wikiwoordenboek audio" in the description line, not the category line.

Answer (score 0):

Using [mwparserfromhell](https://github.com/earwig/mwparserfromhell/)

```
>>> import mwparserfromhell
>>> t = """=={{int:filedesc}}==
... {{Information
... |description = wikiwoordenboek audio
... |date =
... |source =
... |author =
... |permission =
... |other_versions =
... }}
... [[Category:Dutch pronunciation|Example]]"""
>>> for i in mwparserfromhell.parse(t).filter_templates():
...     if 'information' in i.name.lower():
...         i.get('description').value = 'Example'
... 
>>> t
u'{{Information\n|description =Example|date =\n|source =\n|author =\n|permission =\n|other_versions =\n}}'
```